# Is it possible to add an Apple-touch-icon to a sharepoint site?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, apple-touch-icon

I am trying to add an apple-touch-icon to my SharePoint 2010 site. So far I had no luck with SharePoint sites. I added the following code to mater page file. But The same links works on regular web application sites. I am very new to SharePoint. Is there anybody who has had success with it? If so, could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your masterpage :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

If you don't want the default glass effect add this one :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

This is for the new generation with high resolution:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
```

[Apple's source here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: And if you need the image to be sourced from the Style Library, using syntax along these lines: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" runat="server" href="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png%>">
`